# Use multiple tables with identical names or single table with large no. of entries

Tags: mysql

I am making an application that needs to sort out product based on location. A main product table is provided and can be used to refer from each location. Each location can have a different set of reference to main product table.

For eg: area_1 can have product_1 but not product_5.

I am thinking on two approaches that:

1. Have tables table_area(areaId), table_product(productId) and table_area_product(areaId, productId) and sort products based on areaId provided.
2. Have multiple tables such as table_area_product_{areaId}, eg: area_1(table_area_product_1).

[How to write a mysql function with dynamic table name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945882/how-to-write-a-mysql-function-with-dynamic-table-name)
, this link helps on usage of dynamic table name but also says not to use it but I couldn't find any further explanation.

Product data can be 100 000 entries and area data can be up to 300 entries. Both will most probably increase over time.

What is the best approach? Are there other options too?

Comment: I assume 1 lakh is 100,000. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I would have the areas as a separate table, the products table as you have  now and the many_to_many link table (product_id, area_id) that is mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I prefer the same approach but was just concerned that this many entries may prove delay in search queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your ideas are bad for many reasons.

You should have one Product table with no area information in it at all.

You then create a simple cross reference table containing `area` and `product_id`

Lets assume you have areas North/South/East/West

Table name = area_product

```
area   |  product_id
North  |  1
North  |  2
North  |  5
South  |  1
South  |  2
South  |  6
```

And so on.  You then just have to learn how to use JOIN in your query syntax.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM product p
    JOIN area_product ap ON p.id = ap.product_id
WHERE ap.area = 'North'
```

Another benefit of this structure is you can add useful info to this cross reference table **for example only** lets say you want to make a product available only after a specific date in an area.

```
area   |  product_id | start_selling
North  |  1          | 2016-01-01
North  |  2          | 2016-01-01
North  |  5          | 2016-07-01
South  |  1          | 2016-01-01
South  |  2          | 2016-07-01
South  |  6          | 2016-01-01
```

Now to find all available products in the North area you just add a date to the criteria

```
SELECT p.*
FROM product p
    JOIN area_product ap ON p.id = ap.product_id
WHERE ap.area = 'North'
  AND ap.start_selling < NOW()
```

Comment: Yeah, that's actually my first approach but I didn't explain it clearly, my bad. I will edit my question.