# Unknown column error in mysql stored function

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Following is my code of MySQL Stored Function.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `mac_db`$$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `moving_average`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `moving_average`(`table_name` VARCHAR(255),`column_name` VARCHAR(255),`order_column` VARCHAR(255),`row_cnt` INT) RETURNS DOUBLE

    DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN   DECLARE result_avg DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT AVG(`column_name`) INTO result_avg FROM table_name ORDER BY order_column DESC LIMIT row_cnt;

    RETURN result_avg;

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I am calling the function as follows:

```
SELECT moving_average('my_table','my_col','id',4);
```

I am getting the following error.

> Table 'mac_db.table_name' doesn't exist

Please help to resolve the error.

Comment: You cannot parameterize an identifier (such as a table or column name), so you have to use dynamic SQL -- `prepare`.

Comment: OK. Can you please edit the code and guide

Comment: @VrajeshDoshi [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945882/how-to-write-a-mysql-function-with-dynamic-table-name)
may help you out :)

Answer (score 0):

table_name is a parameter not the name of table.

replace you proc parameter as below:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE mac_db$$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS moving_average$$

CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost FUNCTION  moving_average(@table_name VARCHAR(255),@column_name VARCHAR(255),@order_column VARCHAR(255),@row_cnt INT) RETURNS DOUBLE

DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN DECLARE result_avg DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;

SELECT AVG(@column_name) INTO result_avg FROM @table_name ORDER BY @order_column DESC LIMIT @row_cnt;

RETURN result_avg;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@table_name VARCHAR(255),@column_name VARCHAR(255),@order_column VARCHAR(255),@r' at line 1

Comment: try removing @sign while defining variable. `@table_name VARCHAR(255)` with `table_name VARCHAR(255)`